# How can i create a trail of a moving displayObject?

Tags: actionscript-3

some elegant way to create a shadow trail of a object ,e.g a plane?
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871020/as3-create-a-trail-of-movieclips-following-each-other) i can't understand this ,im a starter for as3 . 
so , some directly code should be very good for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var dis : DisplayObject;
    var prevDis : DisplayObject;
    for ( var i:int = _displayList. length -1; i >= 1; i-- ) //reverse recursive
    {
        dis = _displayList[ i ];
        prevDis = _displayList[ i -1 ] ;
        dis . x = prevDis .x;
        dis . y = prevDis .y;     //create ghost shadow effect 
    }

    // need to locate the  first displayObject's position by tween .
    prevDis . x = int (_tween . target. x );
    prevDis . y = int (_tween . target. y );

    _tween . tick( delta );
```

Comment: this is a simple solution for a starter . you can change those displayobjects's color or alpha gradually to make it better .  Another solution is BitmapData copy , you will contact it in future